# "I've graduated" or "I graduated"?

Tags: grammar

Which is more appropriate to use?

> I graduated at Harvard university

Or

> I've graduated at Harvard university

Comment: Actually, I'd use "...from Harvard University".

Answer (score 1):

"I graduated at Harvard university" emphasizes where you graduated, or is neutral. If using the perfect tense, I would (optionally) put in a comma: "I've graduated, at Harvard university". This would imply first and foremost that you're telling us you HAVE graduated, and adding that the university was Harvard.

Comment: not 'at', but 'from'.

Comment: @Mitch, See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202121/historical-basis-for-to-graduate-being-only-a-transitive-verb