# Do I need to use "from" after "graduated"?

Tags: grammaticality

> I graduated high school.
>
> I graduated **from** high school.

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: Both are correct and used frequently  by native speakers.

Comment: @Dan Bron: Which one is more frequent among native speakers; "graduated high school" or "graduated from high school"? When you say native speakers, are you referring to British or Americans?

Comment: Which side of The Pond are you on?

Comment: *[I was graduated](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66490)* some would say, at least in the not-so-distant past.

Answer (score 1):

Graduated **from** seems much more correct to this native American English speaker, but I don't think anyone will call you out for omitting the "from."

Comment: I agree.  But I've had the impression that more Americans are saying *graduated this-or-that* recently. However, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graduated+high+school%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cgraduated+from+high+school%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraduated%20high%20school%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraduated%20from%20high%20school%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) suggests that my impression was wrong.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graduated+college%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cgraduated+from+college%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraduated%20college%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraduated%20from%20college%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0)'s the one for college.

Comment: @Drew - I would tend to regard the sans-from version to be more of a Britishism.

Comment: @HotLicks: being British, I would use a preposition, either *at* or *from* and name the university.  High schools (or better *secondary schools*) do not produce graduates here.

Comment: Do British students finishing secondary school _matriculate [from]_ secondary school?

Comment: @Hot Licks: The sans-from version strikes my American ears as a bit "affected".  But maybe it's just regional. One can't tell from the ngrams. But "graduated university" is _not found at all_ in the BrE corpus.

Answer (score 1):

According to the high school English that I learned 70 years ago, “I graduated high school” is unacceptable. It indicates that it was the school that graduated rather than the subject “I.”

Comment: Welcome to the site, Robert. We are looking for thorough answers supported by references or usage examples from reputable sources. Your answer would be perfectly fine as a comment, but it does't pass muster as an answer. You will be able to post comments when you have earned a few reputation points. Please take the [tour]