# Usage of from, in and at with reference to place of learning

Tags: prepositions

I am slightly confused about the usage of "from" "at" and "in".

```
He was born in England 
He studied at XXX School, Delhi 
He did his schooling from XXX School, Delhi
```

All of these seem to be interchangeable at times, however I am sure there is an underlying principle which is different or it may be the case that I am totally wrong.  Any guidance on the right usage in this is appreciated.

Edit:
Would `He studied in XXX School, Delhi` be the same as `He studied at XXX School, Delhi`

Comment: The third example is wrong.  You might however say "He gained his education from XXX School, Delhi."

Comment: @JHCL That would be grammatically correct, but would be unidiomatic in AmE; the only *from* construction that comes to mind is [*was graduated from* or *graduated from*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66505/16052)— assuming of course that he did graduate.

Comment: @choster - yes, and British Army Officers ['pass out from Sandhurst'](http://www.army.mod.uk/training_education/24486.aspx) (military academy). Both carry the meaning that the student physically leaves (with a qualification).

Comment: Thank you both for the contribution, so from is appropriate only when it means a completion.  However can you think of a word that could indicate completion other than graduation, which I believe cannot be generally used for schools