# "Will" vs. "going to" vs. Present Continious

Tags: word-choice, differences, tenses, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The train will leave” vs. “is going to leave” vs. “leaves” vs. “is leaving”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/the-train-will-leave-vs-is-going-to-leave-vs-leaves-vs-is-leaving)

Here are three sentences:

> David is going to play football next week
>   David is playing football next week
>   David will play football next week

In fact, I don't think that there is a difference between them. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

There is no denotative difference between them.  Their only difference in appropriateness to a particular situation derives from tone and coherence with the audience's habits.

Answer (score 4):

They are all used to describe a future event in different contexts. The choice between them depends on what has gone on previously in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the unanimity, yes, they're all correct; and yes, they all mean the same thing.

Not only that, but there are any number of other ways to express a future event:

- *David plays football next week.*
- *David will be playing football next week.*
- *David is going to be playing football next week.*
- *David is to play football next week.*
- *David is scheduled to play football next week.*

... etc.

(Thank you all, by the way, for not using the phrase *"Future Tense"* here.)