# which one is correct sentence?

Tags: class-based-usage

1.New employee is going to join on Sunday.
2.New employee is joining on Sunday.
3.New employee will join on Sunday.
4.New employee joins on Sunday.

Can you please let me know which sentence i should use form abou and why ?

Comment: They're all wrong for exactly the same reason: you need "A" or "The" before "new employee".

Comment: Perhaps the employee's name is New employee!

Comment: They are all correct, but as Peter Shor says ...

Comment: @Arkamis Which, in English, would be *New **Employee*** (unless she were e.e. cummings).

Comment: You never know with these kids and their names these days. ;)

Comment: Ah HA! Trick question! New employees wouldn't join until MONDAY.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. See [Differences between ways to express future actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/differences-between-ways-to-express-future-actions), [“The train will leave” vs. “is going to leave” vs. “leaves” vs. “is leaving”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/the-train-will-leave-vs-is-going-to-leave-vs-leaves-vs-is-leaving), and the related questions linked from these.