# Could someone explain to me the grammar of this sentence?

Tags: present-tense, future

"My train arrives at 7.30 tomorrow".. or "My train will arrive at 7.30 tomorrow"
Which one is gramatically correct?
Usually I use the future but I heard a lot of people that use the first sentence and I don't understand why.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have to use _will_ when you refer to the future. _Will_ is just another modal auxiliary verb, not "the future tense".  English refers to the future in lots of ways, most of which are in the present tense: _He goes tomorrow; he's going tomorrow; he is to go tomorrow; he's going to go tomorrow_ (pronounced "gonna go"), etc. They're all grammatical.

Comment: Even *he would go tomorrow* is grammatical.

Comment: @Lawrence: *Even if he **went** tomorrow*, it would still be grammatical! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, though it might be a bridge too far (or not!) *had he gone tomorrow*. :)

Comment: @Lawrence: Let's not burn all our contextual bridges! *I'm really surprised he left today. Had he gone tomorrow he could have used a cheap Off-Peak ticket.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Haha, good one!

Comment: @JohnLawler you should write that up as an actual answer, not a comment; posting answers as comments circumvents the standard voting system and means your answer is a lot more likely to vanish. tchrist has written up an answer that's just a direct quote of your comment, so that's not a danger here, but you should really write your own in the future.

Comment: also see: [“The train will leave” vs. “is going to leave” vs. “leaves” vs. “is leaving”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/the-train-will-leave-vs-is-going-to-leave-vs-leaves-vs-is-leaving?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> You don't have to use *will* when you refer to the future. *Will* is just another modal auxiliary verb, not "the future tense".  English refers to the future in lots of ways, most of which are in the present tense: *He goes tomorrow; he's going tomorrow; he is to go tomorrow; he's going to go tomorrow* (pronounced "gonna go"), etc. They're all grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> *My train arrives at 7.30 to*morrow.. or *My train will arrive at 7.30
>   tomorrow.*

Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has
two tenses: present and preterite. Semantically, it is used to make
reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe) but
also for expressing volition (as in *I keep telling my son to get his
hair cut, but he won't*; *so I've told him he has to* --- notice, the
refusals to get his hair cut are in the PAST, and this sentence actually
entails that there IS a haircut in his future!).

*The film will be seen at the Sundance festival* is syntactically a
present tense clause with "will" as the tensed verb. But in that
example, "will" clearly expressed reference to future time ---
something that could be done in various other ways as well (*The film
is going to be seen at the Sundance festival*, *The film is about to
be seen at the Sundance festival*, etc.).