# How do I tell my brother that he needs to wake up early tomorrow?

Tags: phrase-requests

How do I tell my brother that he needs to wake up early tomorrow?

> Tomorrow we are having breakfast together.

Or

> Tomorrow we are going to have breakfast together.

Comment: Because tomorrow what?  Cometh?

Comment: related and with a good answer too!: [When to use present continuous for describing near future instead of using will or going to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235368/when-to-use-present-continuous-for-describing-near-future-instead-of-using-will)

Comment: Related: [What tense should be used here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58316/what-tense-should-be-used-here/58319#58319) and [present continuous or be going to?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168367/present-continuous-or-be-going-to/169193#169193)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would say - Brother, you have to get up early tomorrow, as we'll be having breakfast together.

Comment: —or *because* we’ll be having breakfast together. (Or of course you could just let a bucket of cold water do the talking for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow we will be having breakfast, so wake up early.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. But why *"will"* and not *"are having"* or *"are going  to have"*. It's good to explain your answers.